# Generating CSS stylesheet with PHP creates parse error

Tags: php, css

I am currently on Wordpress 4.1 and want to make variable css values, which get generated via PHP. First I created a file named styling.php that I imported in the default Wordpress stylesheet style.css using `@import url(../genesis/style.css);`

Then I added a simple code into the styling.php, where the content is as follows:

```
   <?php 
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
    $TopColor = #FFE211;
    ?>

    .site-header {
    background-color: <?php echo $TopColor; ?>;
    }
```

But this give me the debugging error "`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>' in line 4`" and I do not know how to fix this

Comment: You need to quote the value `#FFE211`

Comment: put the color in quotes '#FFE211'

Comment: wait, what? Yeah, what everyone else said, you need to quote your $TopColor value.

Comment: I guess those are your css code.So you need them inside `style` tag otherwise it will not work and will output them as plain text at your browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to quote your color:

```
$TopColor = #FFE211;
            ^------^
```

Since it starts with `#`, it's treated as a comment, and the rest of the line is ignored. That means you've effectively got

```
$TopColor = ?>
```

and are missing the assignment value.

Try

```
$TopColor = '#FFE211';
```